# Does annox(https://github.com/highsource/annox) support nested collection object while marshalling/unmarshalling using JAXB?

Tags: java, collections, nested, jaxb, annox

If I have Collection object class member like `ArrayList<ArrayList<Employee>>` in some xyz Class, how to marshall this xyz Class object ?

Analogous with 2D, 3D arrays.

Does annox (https://github.com/highsource/annox) support it?

Is it mandatory to have a wrapper class like `EmployeeList` which will have a member variable as `List<Employee>` and a wrapper above it like `ListOfEmployeeList` which will have a member variable as `List<EmployeeList>`?

Or is it related or equivalent to anyElement of XML.

Comment: What does [tag:annox] has to do with this?

Comment: I still fail to understand how [tag:annox] is relevant here.

Comment: @lexicore if we forget about annox for a while, whats your suggestion for this kind of scenario ?

Comment: As always - first write an XSD which adequately expresses your data structure and then generate your Java code. You might end up with wrapper classes, but I personally don't see big disadvantages of those.

Comment: @lexicore is there any way without wrapper classes for these kind of data structures ? Because I generate these xsd and annox binding files at runtime wherein the plain java class is the input.(plain as in, not using jaxb framework annotations because am using annox https://github.com/highsource/annox)   Please can you share some insight in both JAXB FRAMEWORK SCENARIO and ANNOX SCENARIO

Comment: Because the creator of the Java class doesn't know that these kind of data structures aren't supported(Or I am not aware of handling it in a better way rather than using wrapper classes for such data structures)

Comment: Wrapper classes are the way to go here. I don't think you can really do it differently.